# How to check if tags contain only a specific character in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to check if an input contains a specific character. But I want to know if that input text contains multiple of that character.

For example,

When I have only "," in a textbox, I am able to process the words before it, but I have to check if the whole textbox contains multiple comma's. For example when I press ",,,,".

Any help to check it would do.

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
function changeSubject(current_value) {
    if (current_value != "," && current_value != "") {
        var new_value = current_value.slice(0, -1);
        $(".main-tag-elements").append("<span>" + new_value + "<a class='delete-tag'></a></span>");
        $(".tag-input").val("");
        if ($("#ClassroomSubject").val() == "") {
            $("#ClassroomSubject").val(new_value);
        } else {
            $("#ClassroomSubject").val($("#ClassroomSubject").val() + "," + new_value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('input:contains("one"):contains("second")')
```